# JavaScript(jQuery) | проблема с заменой className для кнопки

Tags: javascript, jquery, классы

У меня есть кнопка. 
Я ей заменяю класс

```
var portalBox = jQuery('#portal-box');
portalBox.find(cancelClass).text('Cancel');
portalBox.find(cancelClass).attr('class','cancel');
```

Класс меняется, всё отлично. Но когда я хочу делать действия с новым классом, ничего не происходит. Будто jQuery не видит его.

```
jQuery('.cancel').on("click", function() {
alert('tested');
```

});

Как сделать так, что когда я меняю кнопке class, я мог работать с новым классом?

Comment: id использовать хоть 1000 раз меняйте class

Comment: также заменял и ID, ничего не происходит.

Comment: id не надо менять ...действие делайте с id а class меняйте сколько угодно id как раз для этого

Comment: Вы меня запутали. Мой ID не меняется в данный момент.
Прочтите ещё раз мой вопрос

Comment: это динамически добавленный элемент ...используйте ID что бы выполнять какое то действие .. либо так `jQuery(document).on("click", "newClass",function()`

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Помогли

Answer (score -1):

У вас не работает т к нужно подписать на событие динамический элемент

```js
$("body").on('click','.E.btn',function(){alert("E");});
$("body").on('click','.C.btn',function(){alert("C");});
$("#changeClass").click(function(){
  $(".btn").toggleClass("E").toggleClass("C").html($(".btn").hasClass("C") ? "C" : "E");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="E btn">E</button>
<button id="changeClass">Change class</button>
```